# Return only last statement from Snowflake SQL query to R

Tags: sql, r, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I've got a Snowflake SQL query I'm trying to execute in R via ODBC connection that looks like this

```
SET quiet=TRUE;

USE SOMEDATABASE.SOMESCHEMA;

--Select timestamp of last sale per customer
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE sales(CustomerId VARCHAR(16777216), SaleTS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9));

INSERT INTO sales
SELECT CustomerId, 
       SaleTS
FROM SALES
WHERE SaleTS>= '2020-11-19 00:00:00'
AND SaleTS <= '2020-11-19 23:59:59.999'
GROUP BY CustomerId;

--Use temp table to get correct row from sales table
SELECT  SUM(SalesDetail.price) as SumPrice
        COUNT(*) as SoldVolume
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN SALES as SalesDetail
    ON Sales.CustomerId = SalesDetail.CustomerId 
    AND sales.SaleTS = SalesDetail.SaleTS
```

Querying Microsoft SQL Server from R I'd normally include `set nocount no;` at the top of the query to ensure only the last step is returned to R to avoid the error `Actual statement count 6 did not match the desired statement count 1.` Error makes sense, SQL is returning 6 components when R is expecting 1 (6 one for each step in my SQL query). In Snowflake there doesn't appear to be an option to set nocount on in the same way. My question is how do I avoid the above error. Does anyone have any experience of executing a mutli-step Snowflake SQL query via R? How can I get R to receive just the last statement from the ODBC connection. So far I've tried `set nocount=TRUE;`, `set echo=FALSE;`, `set message=FALSE;`,  `SET quiet=TRUE` etc

Comment: you are inserting from same table into a temp table and joining back to the same table? why not just  get the sum and count directly?

Comment: and also `SET NOCOUNT ON` option just get rids of count messages sql returns , not the result , if you have multiple set results ( multiple selects)  returning back from sql , you still get nultiple result set in your output

Comment: This is just an example, my actual script is longer and involves more than 1 table. Really would like to solve the mulit-step issue. There are plenty of good reasons to structure a SQL query in this way rather than heavily nested single query approach.

Comment: R see the messages as an output and that's the point I need to stop the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snowflake SQL is expressive enough and proposed code  could  be structured as single query:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CustomerId, MAX(SaleTS) AS SaleTS  -- here agg function is required
    FROM SALES
    WHERE SaleTS>= '2020-11-19 00:00:00'
    AND SaleTS <= '2020-11-19 23:59:59.999'
    GROUP BY CustomerId
)
SELECT  SUM(SalesDetail.price) as SumPrice
        COUNT(*) as SoldVolume
FROM cte
LEFT JOIN SALES as SalesDetail
    ON Sales.CustomerId = SalesDetail.CustomerId 
    AND sales.SaleTS = SalesDetail.SaleTS;
```

The original query is using the same name for both table and temporary table differing only by case `sales` vs `SALES`, which is error-prone.

Second: database and schema could be set up during establishing connection, so there is no need for `USE` inside script. Alternatively fully qualified name could be used in the script.

---

I guess the intent of query is as follow:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM SOMEDATABASE.SOMESCHEMA.SALES
  WHERE SaleTS BETWEEN '2020-11-19 00:00:00' AND '2020-11-19 23:59:59.999'
  QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY SaleTS DESC) = 1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS SoldVolume, SUM(price) as SumPrice
FROM cte;
```

If it is possible that a single person has two entries for exactly the same SaleTS then `RANK() OVER(...)` should be used instead.

Comment: Nice use of `with`, I take your point that in this way you can remove the need for temp tables.

Comment: Note with Oracle, I have often has to do ```SELECT * FROM (WITH cte as (...))``` as the drivers seem to expect ```SELECT``` when calling from R (or VBA).  Just FYI in case OP runs into this in R. +1 as SQL is more expressive than people generally give it credit for.

Comment: what if you are using set var1='test'; before this?  the set is considered a separate statement it seems